# Convert csv rows to associative array

Tags: php, csv, associative-array

I'm having the following csv file

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);

// file
Date,Value1,Value2
17-Nov-17,34,42
16-Nov-17,22,35
15-Nov-17,19,24

$csv = explode("\n", $file);

// dump
array:10 [▼
  0 => "Date,Value1,Value2
  1 => "17-Nov-17,34,42"
  2 => "16-Nov-17,22,35"
  3 => "15-Nov-17,19,24"
]
```

What I want to do is to display the content of the csv file into a html-table, but first I want to convert this to an associative array. How can I do this? Does PHP provide a build-in function for this?

Comment: the **manual** tells you all you have to know: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php - why reinvent the wheel when everything is in place already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with `array_combine`

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);    // Read file into array
$rows = explode("\n", $file);       // Separate lines
$headings = explode(',', $rows[0]); // Turn headings on first line into array
unset($rows[0]);                    // Remove headings from data set
$data = [];
foreach ($rows AS $row)
    $data[] = array_combine($headings, explode(',', $row));
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(9) "17-Nov-17"
    ["Value1"]=>
    string(2) "34"
    ["Value2"]=>
    string(2) "42"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(9) "16-Nov-17"
    ["Value1"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["Value2"]=>
    string(2) "35"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(9) "15-Nov-17"
    ["Value1"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["Value2"]=>
    string(2) "24"
  }
}
```